# Problema de execução assíncrona em servidor node com Express, MySQL e Socket.IO

Tags: mysql, node.js, async, express.js, socket.io

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em Node.JS com Express, MySQL e Socket.IO. Quando o usuário abre a página principal fornecida pelo servidor, a requisição deve fazer com que dados sejam lidos do banco de dados e enviadas ao cliente para que sejam listadas na página.

O problema é que antes que os dados possam ser enviados, o servidor envia a página ao cliente e isso faz com que os dados não sejam lidos do BD ou enviados no socket. Tentei utilizar async para fazer com que todos as funções fossem executadas em ordem, mas não funcionou.

O meu código:

```
app.all("/", function(req, res){ //Função para qualquer requisição HTTP (GET ou POST)

    var query1 = 'SELECT ? FROM tabela1;', query2 = 'SELECT ? FROM tabela2;';

    function qSelect(callback, queryTxt){ //Realiza queries de seleção no bd
        db.query(queryTxt, ['*'], function(err, results){
            if(err){
                console.log("Error on:");
                callback();
                return null;
            }
            callback();
            return results;
        });
    }

    async.series( //Executa comandos em série
        [qSelect(console.log("Table 1 data query."),query1), 
         qSelect(console.log("Table 2 data query."),query2),
         sendDataClient(console.log("Data sent to client."))], 

        function (err, output){ //Função executada após funções enfileiradas em série

            if(err){
                console.log("Error!! Sending database data to client did not result in success.");
                data = [null, null];
            } else{
                data = output;
            }

            io.on("connection", function(callback, socket){
                socket.emit("appData", {msg: "Schedule and Contact Data", content: data});
                socket.on("Return", function (data){
                    console.log(data.content);
                });
            });

        }

    );

res.sendFile("index.html"); //Envia página html ao cliente

});
```

No caso uso Express exclusivamente para lidar com as páginas e requisições http. O Socket.IO é para envio de dados binário ou texto para ser utilizado em javascript no lado do cliente.

Comment: Onde estás a chamar a callback desta linha `io.on("connection"`? Acho que tens de ter o `res.sendFile` dentro da callback do `async.series`, como está corre antes do `ascync` series começar...

Answer (score 1):

Acho que essa mistura de invocar o io.on("connection", ...) dentro do tratador app.all() está errada.

Uma coisa é o Express servir a página; a outra é o Socket.IO servir as requisições dele. São coisas que não se misturam. Provavelmente o cliente está tentando a conexão Socket.IO antes de você ter executado o io.on("connection",...) do lado servidor e aí a conexão já falhou.

Você provavelmente quis iniciar a consulta já durante a carga do index.html, antes da conexão Socket.IO, mas a troco de quê? Talvez ganhar uns milissegundos?

O bloco app.all(...) deve apenas mandar o index.html. Mova todo o bloco do io.on("connection", ...) para fora do app.all(...).

O async.series(...) deve ser invocado dentro do bloco io.on("connection", ...), ou seja, você só consulta o MySQL quando efetivamente a conexão Socket.IO é efetivada, e o socket.emit() é o último passo.

O socket.on("Return", ...) deve ser chamado antes do async.series(...) porque novamente pode acontecer do cliente mandar o Return antes de você ter configurado o respectivo tratador, e a mensagem se perde.

Comment: Eu tenho uma conexão Socket fora da requisição para estabelecer a conexão entre o cliente e o servidor. A minha idéia é fazer a consulta sempre que o cliente abrir index.html para enviar os dados do BD para ele.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acabei resolvendo o meu problema eu mesmo. Depois de tentar *Q*, como outra alternativa ao *async*, reescrevi o código do zero e consegui fazer com que a consulta ao banco de dados fosse realizada antes, simplesmente aninhando as funções de entrega de página (*express*) e de envio de dados (*socket.io*) dentro da função de consulta.

Assim a consulta é realizada e depois a página é enviada ao cliente ao mesmo tempo que os dados obtidos do BD são enviados por socket, atualizando a página enviada.